# Data type mismatch error in opening Record Set

Tags: vba, ms-access

I wrote the following code in VBA

```
    Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub MainButt_Click()
Dim mydb As Database
Dim Frs As DAO.Recordset
Dim Srs As Recordset

Dim strsql As String


strsql = "SELECT * FROM Firstable WHERE TransferDate <'" & Date & "'"
Set Frs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strsql)
Set Srs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("secondtable")
```

and the compiler  gives me an error of a data mismatch error
and stops at the line before the end
if i didn't use the where condition  every thing goes well
so i need to know where is the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is due to the fact that when you concatenate `Date` into the SQL string, you need to wrap it in octothorpes ("#") rather than single quotes:

```
strsql="SELECT * FROM Firsttable WHERE TransferDate<" & Format(Date,"\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")
```

In addition, with dates, you need to ensure that they are unambiguous (is 06/07/20 6th July or 7th June), hence the inclusion of the `Format`. As you are just using the current date, there is actually no need to concatenate the date:

```
strsql="SELECT * FROM Firsttable WHERE TransferDate<Date();"
```

Finally, you may run into problems by using `Set frs=CurrentDb.openRecordset`, as this may go out of scope. Far better to declare a database object, and then use that:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db=DBEngine(0)(0)
Set frs=db.OpenRecordset(strsql)
```

Regards,

Comment: But I think that you to use `Set db=CurrentDb()`, as this then creates a "persistent" object, whereas just using `CurrentDb.OpenRecordset` doesn't.